# Github : Error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: github

I have an issue to push file to my repo.

I have this error message : Error: src refspec master does not match any, as seen here:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone help me get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no branch at all, check if you have at least one commit:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all --branches
```

If not, try at least to make one commit:

```bash
git status
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Check

Comment: Thanks it worked..
But i just want to understand , what I missed ?

Comment: @d4xtian You might have missed the `git status` which helps tells you if you have anything to commit.